# R - How to get / count number of elements belonging to a given name in a named vector in R

Tags: r

For example I have a named vector `x` like this:

```
type_1 type_1 type_3 type_2 type_2 type_1 
134455 165790 837563 370525 377595 547814
```

The first row is names and the second row is values. 
1) How can I calculate the number of each type. For example:

```
type_1 3
type_2 2
type_3 1
```

2) How can I get all elements of a given name, for example type_1

```
type_1 type_1 type_1 
134455 165790 547814
```

Comment: Do you have a vector or a data frame? A vector does not have "first" row.

Comment: by using first row i mean the way it shows up in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the table function and substitution

```
table(names(x))

x[names(x) == "type_1"]
```

Comment: Have you tested the output of your second expression?

Comment: Thanks. table(names(x)) worked but, x["type_1"] didn't. It just gave the first element of type_1.

Comment: Oh. I found a way that is x[names(x) == "type_1"].

Answer (score 1):

```
table(names(x))
#
#type_1 type_2 type_3 
#     3      2      1 
x[names(x) %in% "type_1"]
#type_1 type_1 type_1 
#134455 165790 547814
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(type_1=134455, type_1=165790, type_3=837563, type_2=370525,type_2=377595, type_1=547814)
```